# Error in add method from Wicket version 6.15

Tags: eclipse, version, wicket

I have gotten all the latest jars installed for the Wicket 6.15. I can verify this in the Maven Dependencies directory.

For some reason, I feel it is still pointing to an older version of Wicket. I am getting strange errors with the add method from the MarkupContainer.

Using the quick-start example, in the HomePage class I am getting an error with:

add(new Label("message", "If you see this message wicket is properly configured and running"));

The error is:
The method add(Component[]) in the type MarkupContainer is not applicable for the arguments (Label)

Not sure why it is using Component[] as a argument and not Component... childs

as I am used to.

I am using Eclipse.

Comment: you can add multiple components in the add() method like so `add(label1, label2);` so you always pass an array even if you only supply one argument. This reason this might not be working is because of your jdk version, it should be jdk5+.

Answer (score 0):

Check your import statements.  You probably accidentally imported a different `Label` instead of `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label`.